# Can't execute unit tests for SQLiteOpenHelper implementation in Android project

Tags: java, android, sqlite, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to execute Android Unit tests with Context, but it throws an error at creating database on test package on the method with `@BeforeClass` annotation

The `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation is following:

```
public class SqLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private SqLiteHelper(Context context, String name, int version, AppProperties props) {
    super(context, name, null, version);
    this.context = context;
    this.props = props;
    this.db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  public static SqLiteHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    INSTANCE = Optional.ofNullable(INSTANCE).orElseGet(() -> {
      AppProperties props = new AppProperties(context, AppConstants.DATABASE_PROPERTIES); // create an instance with some properties
      String name = props.getProperty(Database.DATABASE_NAME); // database_name
      int version = props.getIntProperty(Database.DATABASE_VERSION); // 1
      return new SqLiteHelper(context, name, version, props);
    });
    return INSTANCE;
  }

  // more code
}
```

And test class is:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SqLiteHelperTest extends TestCase {

  private static SqLiteHelper helper;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setup() {
    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();
    helper = SqLiteHelper.getInstance(context); // throws exception
    // more configuration
  }
  // tests
}
```

The exception stack trace is:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/data/user/0/pe.com.disceria.moanalarm.test/databases/alarm_moan_test': Directory /data/user/0/pe.com.disceria.moanalarm.test/databases doesn't exist
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:252)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:205)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:505)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:198)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:918)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:898)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:762)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:751)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:373)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
at my.app.pack.sqlite.SqLiteHelper.<init>(SqLiteHelper.java:34)
at my.app.pack.sqlite.SqLiteHelper.lambda$getInstance$0(SqLiteHelper.java:42)
at my.app.pack.sqlite.SqLiteHelper$$ExternalSyntheticLambda7.get(Unknown Source:2)
at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:263)
at my.app.pack.sqlite.SqLiteHelper.getInstance(SqLiteHelper.java:38)
at my.app.pack.sqlite.SqLiteHelperTest.setup(SqLiteHelperTest.java:41)
... 24 trimmed
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:224)
... 41 more
```

But when I enter on my device, I see that the route '/data/user/0/my.app.pack.test/' already exists, so how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I forgot it: the min API version is 26